# Handle psycopg2.InternalError 'ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block'

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I encountered a problem as title depicted:

```
InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

I found 3 solutions:

1. `with` statement;
2. `rollback()`;
3. `autocommit` attribute; (seems too global)

I have tried `with` statement, but not work with my situation. Here, I need `cursor` for later use, I builded a `get()` method like Django, so it can't be closed.

Well, I think i can catch the certain error to perform `rollback()`, then to `execute()`. Due to `InternalError` is a mixed exceptions, I catch the error based on `pgerror` attribute.

```
class PostgresqlConnector(object):

    def __init__(self, config):
        self.conn = psycopg2.connect(**config)
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

        # Add exceptions
        self.DoesNotExist = DoesNotExist
        self.MultipleObjectsReturned = MultipleObjectsReturned

    def __commit__(self):
        self.conn.commit()

    def __rollback__(self):
        self.conn.rollback()

    def __execute__(self, sql, vals):
        try:
            self.cursor.execute(sql, vals)
        except psycopg2.InternalError as e:
            if e.pgerror == 'ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block\n':
                self.__rollback__()
                return self.__execute__(sql, vals)
            raise e
        else:
            self.__commit__()
            return self.cursor

    def select(self, tab, query_dict, cols_selected='*', filter_='='):
        cols, vals = zip(*query_dict.items())
        cols_selected = ', '.join(cols_selected)
        expr_where = ' AND '.join(["{} {} %s".format(x, filter_) for x in cols])

        sql = "SELECT {} FROM \"{}\" WHERE {}".format(cols_selected, tab, expr_where)
        return self.__execute__(sql, vals)

    # --- omit ---

    def get(self, tab, query_dict, cols_selected='*', filter_='='):
        # here i need cursor
        self.cursor = self.select(tab, query_dict, cols_selected, filter_)
        if self.cursor.rowcount == 1:
            return self.cursor.fetchone()
        elif self.cursor.rowcount == 0:
            raise self.DoesNotExist("No record found!")
        else:
            raise self.MultipleObjectsReturned("Get {} records! only one excepted.".format(self.cursor.rowcount))

    def close(self):
        self.cursor.close()
        self.conn.close()
```

My question is that am i doing right? Any better solutions?

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.